# all sites are down after switching IIS6 in 32bit mode

Tags: iis-6

I;ve recently switched IIS6 to 32 bit mode and none of my sites (framework 2.0 and 4.0 ) are running now. it says "Service Unavailable"

Here is what I've done:
followed the steps from : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934162

Any help?

Answer:
(1) Convert the 64bit w2k3 to 32 using above article.
(2) aspnet_regiis -i for .net 2.0 and 4.0 both
(3) restart
(4) you will notice website properties in IIS will not have ASP.NET TAB
(5) download iis6 utility to change .net framework version
(6) configure reporting server and set the websites for the same to asp.net 2.0
(7) all is done well and working fine

Comment: How did you do the switch? What did you do to fix it? Right now this is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an ISAPI Filter or other module that references a 64-bit DLL?  That's the most likely cause.  Try pulling out all of your filters and handlers to get a good test page.  You can also create a new app pool and create a simple 'hello world' page to confirm that it's not something at the server level.  Then start adding back parts until you narrow down the cause.

If you haven't already, check Event Viewer for clues too.